# How to run and view celery task in Django?

Tags: python, django, task, celery

I am working on an email crawler for learning purposes 
and I am having trouble to understand how to run the task and view what task is still running on background.

in my views.py:

```
def home(request):
form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    save_it= form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    messages.success(request,"Working, please wait........")
    baseurl=form.cleaned_data['site']
    maxemails=form.cleaned_data['max_emails']
    maxurl=form.cleaned_data['max_links']
    startcraw.delay(baseurl,maxurl,maxemails)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')
#form not valid
return render_to_response("signup.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in tasks.py i have :

```
from celery import task
from .craw import crawler
@task()
def startcraw(base,url,emails):
    f = open('myfile','w')
    f.write('hi there\n') # python will convert \n to os.linesep
    f.close()
    list= crawler(base,url,emails)
    list.save()
```

I tried to debug with the write to file line

How can i know if the crawler is even running and how can I save/pull the result to my database (SQLite) 
any help will be appreciate

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Celery Logger. 
Simple example:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('started adding function at time {0}'.format(datetime.now()))
    return x + y
```

It is described here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging
Actually Celery has good docs so all info could be found there.
Also I think that you need scheduled tasks for such objectives like crawling.
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: but for some reason my func startcraw not working..., no file name myfile is found